# What is the complete specification for typing values into Etherscan write contract?

Tags: etherscan

You can type in:

1. addresses
2. integers
3. strings
4. booleans
5. bytes
6. arrays of items 1–7
7. structs of items 1–7

Please fully specify all acceptable ways to type each of those into that box.

[image]